# submitting form with dynamic field in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Functionality:** when I do add resource in `form A`. The resource is displayed into `form B`. Then I need to submit the `form B`.

I am not able to submit it. Main reason is : all the fields which is shown in `form B` is in loop. So I am unable to give specific name for each field.

[image]

**HTML** `Codes of form B`

```
<form id="attendanceSheet" name="attendanceSheet" ng-submit="fillupAttendanceSheet(attendanceSheet.$valid)" >                   
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in resources">
        <td data-title="'Billable Resource'" style="text-align:center"><b>{{resource.resource_name}}</b></td>                               
        <td data-title="'Working Hours'" style="text-align:center"><input type="number" style="width: 55px;" min="0" max="8" ng-model="timeSheetTest.hour" value="8" required></td>
        <td data-title="'Working Hours'" style="text-align:center"><input type="number" style="width: 55px;" ng-model="timeSheetTest.nonhour" min="0" max="8" required></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="span2">
    <button name="loginBtn" type="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Submit Sheet</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**controller.js** `codes of form B`

```
var addTimeSheet = function(timeSheetTest) {
console.log(timeSheetTest);  // here I should get the form values
}

$scope.fillupAttendanceSheet = function(isFormValid) {
    if(isFormValid){
        addTimeSheet($scope.timeSheetTest);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $index to create new field for each row `timeSheetTest[$index].hour`

```
    <input type="number" style="width: 55px;" min="0" max="8" ng-model="timeSheetTest[$index].hour" value="8" required>
```

this way you get array of objects...

Comment: I'll check and let you know. :)

Comment: when I click on working hours column it gives me this error in console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hour' of undefined`

Comment: just do `ng-init="timeSheetTest[$index] = {}"`